# Finding the upper bound of an integral problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

(a) I have to find the find the upper bound  $\beta$ of the integral $I_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx= \int_{0}^{\beta }sds$ where $0<a<1$.

(b) Using the results of (a) I have to find the function $f(s)$ such that $I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx=\int_{0}^{\beta }f(s)ds$. $f(s)$ has a single maximum point in the domain $0\leq s\leq \beta$.

For (a), I tried to substitute $s=\frac{1}{x^{2}+a^{2}}$ but when I tried to take the derivative of both sides and express $x$ in terms of $s$ things got ugly

$$ds=\frac{-2x}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{2}}dx$$

$$x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1+sa^{2}}{s}}$$

$$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx=\int_{0}^{\beta }s\frac{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{2}ds}{-2x}=\int_{0}^{\beta } \pm \frac{1}{2s\sqrt{\frac{1-sa^2}{s}}}ds$$

Then I tried to take a different approach. Since the solution for $$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx$$ is $\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{a}$ and $ \int_{0}^{\beta }sds=\frac{\beta^2 }{2}$

I figured that the only value of $\beta$ that would make sense is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{a}}$. Having gotten this result I don't know what should I do for (b). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{1}{a}=\frac{\beta^2 }{2}$

$$I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{a^2 \sqrt{1 + a^2}}=\int_0^\beta f(s)ds$$

take derivative:

$$\frac{d}{d\beta}\frac{1}{a^2 \sqrt{1 + a^2}}=f(\beta)\Rightarrow f(\beta)=\frac{d}{da}\frac{1}{a^2 \sqrt{1 + a^2}}\cdot \frac{da}{d\beta}$$

Next, you need to take derivative and simplify, finally express $a$ with $\beta$ by using $\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{1}{a}=\frac{\beta^2 }{2}$ (maybe implicitly).